# Trying to sort my movie list by negative and positive

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, text-formatting, notepad, list

i hope this is not too off topic. Tried thinking of sites to help me with this but i hope this is ok.

I have a list with 553 movies, a notepad .txt file with titles formatted just like this:

```
Shutter Island
The Dark Knight
Gravity
Black Swan
The Fast and the Furious: Tokyo Drift
```

Now i want to sort all of these by negative & positive. I tried using google for help but didn't really find anything other than these. (Sort alphabetically etc:  http://sortmylist.com/ https://www.online-utility.org/text/sort.jsp)

I know i could just remake the whole list since i don't have any predefined value for negative or positive so you would think it would take just as long anyways.

But i just want a way i can drag the names or click a button to choose group (negative / positive) so it goes faster because copy pasting, erasing and formatting 530 lines is just gonna make me go crazy.........

I also have Microsoft Excel if this could help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your list has only film name no other attribute as you have written +ve or  -ve. And if  you are desperate to use them to reshuffle the films  then need to add adjacent column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean you want to assign each movie positive or negative based on your personal preference.

1. Open the text file in Excel. (Or select them from Notepad and paste them into Excel.)
2. Movies will appear in column A. In column B, type P or N next to each movie. (Or to save time, just P next to the positive movies, leaving blank for negative movies.)
3. Select columns A and B then sort by column B (and optionally column A as the second level sort if you'd like the the titles sorted.)

Now all your movies are grouped in the list. You can paste them into Notepad or another Excel workbook or wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mike's answer:

You definitely need to add columns, you can do it in Excel, but you should export as tab-delimited text-file, so your data doesn't get eaten in program upgrade hell in the coming decades.

I add rating first, because it is not as variable length as film names.

You should also include the year, as they're naming films more poorly recently - but mpaa prevents duplicate names per year.  Could be a separate column, or appended to the end of the film name.  In addition you should consider alternate film names (eg: Live. Die. Repeat.).

I also include a date watched/rated in my text files as an additional field; so I have some idea of when I rated it.  Doubles as a 'what did I watch last' list.

I also own movies; so I put if I own a copy (digital, bluray, dvd, laser, vhs) or if it is on my want list.